# ForEach: No exact matches in call to initializer

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm new in iOS developing but I would know why I can't iterate with my RssItem. Here my code.

```
import SwiftUI
import FeedKit

let feedURL = URL(string: "http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss")!

struct RssList: View {

    let parser = FeedParser(URL: feedURL)
    var rssFeed: RSSFeed?


    @State private var items: [RSSFeedItem]? = [RSSFeedItem]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    RssItem(feed: item)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Feed")
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    await GetRss()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func GetRss() async {
        async let feed = parser.parse()
        
        do {
            items = try await feed.get().rssFeed?.items
            print("Done")
           } catch {
               print("Sorry, there was a network problem.")
           }
    }
}

struct RestTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RssList()
    }
}
```

I've tried passing ad in inside foreach but not working.
Need I a different way to achieve it or I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `items` is an optional.  You are providing a default, empty list, so remove the ? from the declaration.

Comment: Note, you should be using `https:`, not `http:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paulw11 mentioned in the comments, the first issue is that `items` is optional. You can fix that either by removing the `?` or by wrapping the `ForEach` in an `if let` statement:

```
if let items = items {
    ForEach(items) {...}
}
```

If that doesn't fix it, check if `RSSFeedItem` conforms to `Identifiable`. If not, you have two options:

1. Make it conform to `Identifiable`:

   ```
   struct RSSFeedItem: Identifiable {

       let id: Int

       // Other properties..
       let uniqueProperty: Int
   }
   ```
2. Add an id to the `ForEach` initializer:

   ```
   // Use one property as an identifier

   ForEach(items, id: \.uniqueProperty) { item in
       RssItem(feed: item)
   }

   // Or use the whole item as an identifier

   ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
       RssItem(feed: item)
   }
   ```